# How to change the image background to white?

Tags: java, image-processing, marvin-framework, marvinproject

I have set of images. Images have a simple background. I want to change that background to white using [Marvin Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/) and Java.

As I am new to Marvin, it is making me trouble to change the background. I also tried opencv for java but its giving unsatisfied link error.

**Image Example:**

[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit difficult to understand, would you edit it by following [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Comment: In a graphical editor one would use a magic lasso or wand, select the background and fill it. Or flood fill with some threshold of color difference. At a glance at that fine project I did not see anything like that.

Answer (score 5):

To get a perfect result you'll need to find a way to remove shadows. But I think it is a good start point for you.

**Algorithm:**

1. Convert the image to binary color model (pixels are true or false) given a gray scale threshold.
2. Perform a morphological dilation for closing openings in the shoes boundary.
3. Fill the background with color rgb(255,0,255)
4. After filling the background with a new color in the binary image, set the same pixels to white in the original image.

**output:**

[image]

**source code:**

```
import static marvin.MarvinPluginCollection.*;

public class RemoveBackground {

    public RemoveBackground(){
        MarvinImage image = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/shoes.jpg");
        MarvinImage bin = MarvinColorModelConverter.rgbToBinary(image, 116);
        morphologicalDilation(bin.clone(), bin, MarvinMath.getTrueMatrix(5, 5));
        MarvinImage mask = MarvinColorModelConverter.binaryToRgb(bin);
        boundaryFill(mask.clone(), mask, 5, 5, new Color(255,0,255));


        for(int y=0; y<mask.getHeight(); y++){
            for(int x=0; x<mask.getWidth(); x++){
                if(mask.getIntColor(x, y) == 0xFFFF00FF){
                    image.setIntColor(x, y, 255,255,255);
                }
            }
        }
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(image, "./res/shoes_out.jpg");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RemoveBackground();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.awt.Color cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer - this is the error i m getting while running program

Comment: I was able to solve by using the jar file from this [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/marvin-project/9ZgLtsjtkpc) using this [jar file](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/files/org.marvinproject.image.fill.boundaryFill.jar)

Comment: this works exactly as told...with marvin it was easy to do , we are going to make setup of marvin easy way